# linker --as-needed flag not pruning libraries

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I'm running into an issue after upgrading gcc from 4.1.1 to 4.7.2.  The problem is that the ld --as-needed flag is not pruning libraries that are not required if enough libraries with inter dependencies are listed.

For example, if I build a simple program that doesn't need any special libraries, but includes them on the build line, as such

```
gcc -m32 test.c -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/local/lib -lrt -lprojcommon -lproj -lrte  -o test
```

then it builds fine and the --as-needed flag does it's job pruning out all of the listed libs that are not needed.

```
ldd test
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00bfc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x001ac000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0018a000
```

However, if I add one more library (in this case crypto), then the build fails with undefined reference errors.

```
gcc -m32 test.c -Wl,--as-needed -L/usr/local/lib -lcrypto -lrt -lprojcommon -lproj -lrte  -o test

/usr/local/lib/librte.so: error: undefined reference to 'tla_decap_data'
/usr/local/lib/librte.so: error: undefined reference to 'do_db'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This exact same build worked with 4.1.1, but started failing with 4.7.2.

This is part of a general build infra and libraries included on the build line are generic and expected to be pruned via --as-needed.  I could fix this with --allow-shlib-undefined, but I'd prefer to find real unresolved symbols at build time.  If I do set --allow-shlib-undefined, then I end up with the same set of required libs as the build that worked.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Is test.c just `int main(){return 0;}` or does it have more content that could use an unlucky name? If you remove -lrte, does it work, and what libraries are actually linked? Are all the libs .so or is one of them a .a?

Comment: Yes, test.c is just an empty main function.  All are shared .so libraries.  If I remove any single one of not required libs in [-lcrypto, -lprojcommon, -lproj, -lrte] then the linking works and the actually linked libraries remains the same as if I list them all and use --allow-shlib-undefined, [linux-gate.so, libc.so, ld-linux.so].  I'm starting to think that this may be a linker bug...

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to report it to the linker guys (http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/ for GNU binutils), though you may want to try it with a more recent version of ld first so your report is given more consideration. Please remember to post the result here once they find out what is going on.